# Moving to next activity after successful facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have added the facebook login feature to my app.
It works if you login once and give you the user token. However I want it to move to the next activity.

I know I have a typo activity wrong in the test activity.
Once logged in the app crashes straight away.
The code is below, any ideas?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LoginButton loginButton;
TextView loginStatusText;
CallbackManager callbackManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
    loginStatusText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginStatusText);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //What happens when the user logs in.

           // loginStatusText.setText("Login Sucessfull \n" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" +loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Intent testactivty = new Intent("uk.co.cyclesavy.cyclesavy.TestActivty");
            startActivity(testactivty);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            loginStatusText.setText("Login Cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the crash you are seeing, please add the log. Did you put your activities in the Manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix your Intent.

Instead of

```
Intent testactivty = new Intent("uk.co.cyclesavy.cyclesavy.TestActivty");
```

Try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find how to start a new Activity with Intent:

- [Android Dev - Starting Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

Be sure to define the `Activity` you are switching to in `AndroidManifest.xml` !!